# How to fix " The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption" error

Tags: java, sql-server

I am trying to connect MS SQL server 2016 through java. I am using JDK1.8 and mssql-jdbc-7.2.1.jre8.jar file.

```
public class ConnectToMSSQL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestSQL;user=sa;password=password";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

While running the above code, got the below error, how to fix this?

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "RSA premaster secret error". ClientConnectionId:8438be77-02cd-4d82-b84d-16c0045ac415
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2887)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1881)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2452)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2103)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1950)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1162)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:735)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at database.ConnectToMSSQL.main(ConnectToMSSQL.java:12)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error
    at sun.security.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1799)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SunTls12RsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(KeyGenerator.java:169)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyGenerator(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Looks like the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) is missing from your classpath? If you are using OpenJDK it should be in the `lib/ext` directory called `sunjce_provider.jar`.

Comment: hi, sunjce_provider.jar file is available in 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext' path.

Comment: What does this program print with the classpath setting of your project: https://gist.github.com/hackbert/079df85e2b0befb188d235b57bd3cb76 ?
 
On a side note: That JDK version is pretty outdated. If you can do an update you should.

Comment: I just downloaded the exact same version of the JDK you are using and `KeyGenerator.getInstance("SunTls12RsaPremasterSecret");` works like a charm. I am on Linux though, but still I think the JCE might not get loaded in your case.

Comment: Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 2):

It is working fine now.
Just I have done the following: in Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > removed and added the same JDK path, now it is working fine.